# Convert average from lambda stream to Integer

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream, collectors

I have a map and would like to have an integer instead of a double but I can't seem to get it to convert. My problem seems to be the 'averagingInt' part. I get the correct value, I just want to round it down. Thank you in advance.

```
public Map<String,Integer> executeSQL14(){
    return records.stream()
            .filter(p->p.getSource().equals("a") || p.getSource().equals("b"))
            .filter(p->p.getDestination().equals("f") || p.getDestination().equals("h"))
            .filter(p->p.getExtendedSecurityCheck().equals("n"))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Record::getDestination, Collectors.averagingInt(Record::getWeight)));
}
```

Comment: If this method is processing the results from an SQL query, maybe you should do all the filtering and aggregation directly in SQL, not in Java. Just saying.

Comment: please share the result you expected

Comment: What's the issue? Is `Record::getWeight` returning a double instead of an int? You can change it to `Collectors.averagingInt(r -> (int) r.getWeight())`

Comment: @Eran getWeight() returns an int but the method averagingInt produces a double. Sadly, I can't get it to work with your code. It can't resolve the method 'getWeight' then.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez This is an exercise to learn about lambda streams, so I try to to do everything with it.

Comment: @Ruslan I expect a String like 'a' and a value like '18' but instead of '18' I get something like '18.000802'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You possibly could use the alternative `toMap` as:

```
public Map<String,Integer> executeSQL14(List<Record> records) {
    return records.stream()
            .filter(p -> p.getSource().equals("a") || p.getSource().equals("b"))
            .filter(p -> p.getDestination().equals("f") || p.getDestination().equals("h"))
            .filter(p -> p.getExtendedSecurityCheck().equals("n"))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Record::getDestination, Record::getWeight, (a, b) -> (a + b) / 2));
}
```

or possibly perform an additional finishing operation using `collectingAndThen` as:

```
public Map<String,Integer> executeSQL14(List<Record> records) {
    return records.stream()
            .filter(p -> p.getSource().equals("a") || p.getSource().equals("b"))
            .filter(p -> p.getDestination().equals("f") || p.getDestination().equals("h"))
            .filter(p -> p.getExtendedSecurityCheck().equals("n"))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Record::getDestination, 
                    Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.averagingInt(Record::getWeight), Double::intValue)));
}
```

Comment: I tried both solutions and the second one is the solution to my problem. Thank you so much!